# How to select all values of multiselect picklist selected by defaullt on visual force page

Tags: visualforce, multi-select

I have requirement where I want to keep all value as selected in multi select picklist on visual force page.

as far as I know I can select one value as default selected on normal picklist but how to do that for multiselect picklist ?

Is there any standard approach to this ? Or Script to achieve that?

Here is my controller

```
 /****************
    Constructor
    ****************/
    public LeaseActionEdit_TempController(ApexPages.StandardController stdCont)
    {
      recordTypeId = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('RecordType');        
        isClone = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('clone');      
        isUnitRedemised = false;             
         if (Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().containsKey('id'))
        {
            oppId = stdCont.getId();           
        } 
    }

      /****************
            Method to get value in opp
            ****************/

        public PageReference doLoad()
            {
                List<Opportunity> lsOpp = new List<Opportunity>();

                if (oppId != null && oppId != '')
                {
                    lsOpp = [SELECT Maintain__c  FROM Opportunity WHERE Id =: oppId
};

             opp = lsOpp[0];
}

/******************************
your code snippet on controller
************************************/
 public static List<String> getPickListValues(String TenantShallMaintain) {
        List<String> res = new List<String> ();
        for (Schema.PickListEntry ple: getPickListEntries(TenantShallMaintain))
            res.add(ple.getValue());
        return res;
    }
private static List<Schema.PickListEntry> getPickListEntries(String TenantShallMaintain) {
        return Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(TenantShallMaintain.split('\\.')[0]).getDescribe().fields.getMap().get(TenantShallMaintain.split('\\.')[1]).getDescribe().getPickListValues();
    }
}
```

Comment: prepopulate the list bound to the multiselect selectList to all the choices (obtained from the schema)

Comment: can you elaborate this? I did not understand.

Comment: is this a roll-your-own multiselect list using `apex:selectList` ? or are you trying to default an `apex:inputField` ?

Comment: this is default apex:inputfield.

Answer (score 3):

Let's start with two utility methods to return a list of strings corresponding to any Picklist-type Sobject.Fldname:

```
public static List<String> getPickListValues(String sObjNameDotFldName) {
        List<String> res = new List<String> ();
        for (Schema.PickListEntry ple: getPickListEntries(sObjNameDotFldName))
            res.add(ple.getValue());
        return res;
    }
private static List<Schema.PickListEntry> getPickListEntries(String sObjNameDotFldName) {
        return Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(sObjNameDotFldName.split('\\.')[0]).getDescribe().fields.getMap().get(sObjNameDotFldName.split('\\.')[1]).getDescribe().getPickListValues();
    }
```

Then, if you want to prepopulate an Sobject field bound to an `apex:inputField`

```
mySobject.myField = String.join(getPickListValues('MyObject.MyField'),';');
```

Using your example, after you fetch `opp` in `doLoad()`,

```
opp.maintain__c = String.join(getPickListValues('Opportunity.Maintain__c');
```

=========================

If, on the other hand, you are doing a roll-your-own MSP using an `apex:selectlist` like the following:

```
<apex:selectList value="{!selectedVals}" multiselect="true">
  <apex:selectOptions value="{!availVals}"/>
</apex:selectList>
```

your Controller will need a getter for `availVals` and a getter/setter for `selectedVals` as follows:

```
public SelectOption[] getAvailVals() {
  SelectOption[] res = new List<SelectOption>(); 
  for (String s : getPickListValues('MyObject.MyField')) // e.g 'Opportunity.MyMspField__c'
      res.add(new SelectOption(s,s);
  return res;
}

public String[] selectedVals {
   get {
       if (this.selectedVals == null) // assumes some entry is required o.w. initialize in constructor
          this.selectedVals = new List<String>(getPickListValues('MyObject.MyField'));
       return this.selectedVals;
   }
   set;
 }
```

during the save actionmethod (or equivalent), you interrogate the selected values by referring to `this.selectedVals`

*there may be typos in the above*

Comment: Ok let me try implementing in my org. I will keep you posted with the outcome. I really appreciate your all efforts to write this for me. I will keep you posted on the same.  Thanks

Comment: hey one quick question

I cant pass actuall sObjName.FldName as string here can I ? did you mean that or was this "sObjNameDotFldName" only a string?  for this line on controller 
public static List<String> getPickListValues(String sObjNameDotFldName) {

Comment: i updated the answer with an example

Comment: I am not using select list I am only using standard <apex:inputtext field>.  so I understand where should I add this line on visual force page mySobject.myField = String.join(getPickListValues(),';');

Comment: here is the input field on visual force force page I am using 
 <apex:inputField value="{!opp.Maintain__c}" id="OppMaintain" />
how do I use your code snippet with the inputfield part?

Comment: you'll need to post your controller (only relevant bits only please - constructor, declaration of `opp`, etc) by editing your question

Comment: I have edited my question with that controller details that you have asked me to enter . Please have a look.

Comment: i edited my answer -- but in your utility methods, replace `TenantShallMaintain` with `sobjectNameDotField` or perhaps, simply `objFld` as it is simply the definition of the argument used by the method (which really belong in a Utility class so they can be reused elesewhere in your org

Comment: Hey i am getting this error while adding that line on my doLoad() 
"Variable does not exist: String"

Comment: also I don't understand where to add this line on my controller or VF page?

"mySobject.myField = String.join(getPickListValues('MyObject.MyField'),';');"

Comment: Ricky - I can't infer what the issue is unless you update the question with the latest code.